# Ansible - Extract values from nested dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I want to extract values from a nested dictionary. The dictionary is

```
"customers": {
    "customer_1": [
        {
            "c1_cluster_1": [
                {
                    "primary": [
                        "c1_server_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "secondaries": [
                        "c1_server_2",
                        "c1_server_3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tiebreakers": [
                        "c1_server_4",
                        "c1_server_5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c1_cluster_2": [
                {
                    "primary": [
                        "c1_server_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "secondaries": [
                        "c1_server_2",
                        "c1_server_3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tiebreakers": [
                        "c1_server_4",
                        "c1_server_5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c1_cluster_3": [
                {
                    "primary": [
                        "c1_server_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "secondaries": [
                        "c1_server_2",
                        "c1_server_3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tiebreakers": [
                        "c1_server_4",
                        "c1_server_5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "customer_2": [
        {
            "c2_cluster_1": [
                {
                    "primary": [
                        "c2_server_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "secondaries": [
                        "c2_server_2",
                        "c2_server_3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tiebreakers": [
                        "c2_server_4",
                        "c2_server_5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c2_cluster_2": [
                {
                    "primary": [
                        "c2_server_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "secondaries": [
                        "c2_server_2",
                        "c2_server_3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tiebreakers": [
                        "c2_server_4",
                        "c2_server_5"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to have a list of unique server names per customer, the Cluster number or server role are not needed. End result would be

```
customer_servers: [
  customer_1: [
    "c1_server_1",
    "c1_server_2",
    "c1_server_3",
    "c1_server_4",
    "c1_server_5"
  ],
  customer_2: [
    "c2_server_1",
    "c2_server_2",
    "c2_server_3",
    "c2_server_4",
    "c2_server_5"
  ]
]
```

I've tried the following

```
    - name: use Jinja to extract only the customer names and server names from customers 
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cust_servers: |
          {% for cust in customers %}
          {{ cust.key }}:
          {% for serv in cust.value %}
          {% for k, v in serv.items() %}
            - {{v}}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
    
    - name: Convert cust_servers to a dictionary 
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cust_servers_dict: "{{cust_servers|from_yaml}}"
```

I've also attempted to break down the components of customers using debug but, have failed to get to the level that I wanted

```
- name: print the customer dictionary component parts
  debug:
    msg:
      - "ClusterName is {{customers[0].key}} and it's value is"
      - "{{customers[0].value}}
      - " ----------------------------------------------------- "
      - "{{customers[0].value[0].values()}}
```

My intention with this second attempt was to loop through the customer list but it became apparent that i might need multiple loops with this approach and i was probably over complicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
  customer_servers_keys: "{{ customers.keys()|list }}"
  customer_servers_vals: "{{ customers.values()|
                             map('ansible.utils.to_paths')|
                             map('dict2items')|
                             map('map', attribute='value')|
                             map('unique')|list }}"
  customer_servers: "{{ dict(customer_servers_keys|
                             zip(customer_servers_vals)) }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  customer_servers:
    customer_1: [c1_server_1, c1_server_2, c1_server_3, c1_server_4, c1_server_5]
    customer_2: [c2_server_1, c2_server_2, c2_server_3, c2_server_4, c2_server_5]
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    customers:
      customer_1:
        - c1_cluster_1:
          - primary: [c1_server_1]
          - secondaries: [c1_server_2, c1_server_3]
          - tiebreakers: [c1_server_4, c1_server_5]
        - c1_cluster_2:
          - primary: [c1_server_1]
          - secondaries: [c1_server_2, c1_server_3]
          - tiebreakers: [c1_server_4, c1_server_5]
        - c1_cluster_3:
          - primary: [c1_server_1]
          - secondaries: [c1_server_2, c1_server_3]
          - tiebreakers: [c1_server_4, c1_server_5]
      customer_2:
        - c2_cluster_1:
          - primary: [c2_server_1]
          - secondaries: [c2_server_2, c2_server_3]
          - tiebreakers: [c2_server_4, c2_server_5]
        - c2_cluster_2:
          - primary: [c2_server_1]
          - secondaries: [c2_server_2, c2_server_3]
          - tiebreakers: [c2_server_4, c2_server_5]

# Expected result
#   customer_servers:
#     - customer_1: [c1_server_1, c1_server_2, c1_server_3, c1_server_4, c1_server_5]
#     - customer_2: [c2_server_1, c2_server_2, c2_server_3, c2_server_4, c2_server_5]


    customer_servers_keys: "{{ customers.keys()|list }}"
    customer_servers_vals: "{{ customers.values()|
                               map('ansible.utils.to_paths')|
                               map('dict2items')|
                               map('map', attribute='value')|
                               map('unique')|list }}"
    customer_servers: "{{ dict(customer_servers_keys|
                               zip(customer_servers_vals)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: customer_servers|to_yaml
```